# How to see a record of amendments to flight schedules?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, delays, compensation, virgin-atlantic

My flight from Delhi to London with Virgin Atlantic was delayed by more than 5 hours on Thursday 18th April. I am trying to get the official takeoff and landing time for this flight but can't find it any more.
Virgin have told me that they were delayed because they only knew that Pakistan Airspace was closed 4 days prior to the flight, but in reality they had been avoiding it since it was 1st closed in Feb 2019.
There was an additional delay for technical reasons hence the 5 hours delay.

Comment: I have clicked on all the links marked as duplicate above, and can't find my question on any of the links that came up. Why is this?